# Image is not fixed in the div?

Tags: html, dialog

I have a div in which i need to put differant size images. I used max-height , the div size varies according the size of image. It is ok if the image is small My problem is if the image is large, it is coming out of the div.
can i fix it in the div? here is the html

```
     <div id="zoomdialog" style="display:none">
         <div style="border:1px solid black; top:0%; right:1%; 
          position:absolute;cursor:pointer;" class="zoomremoveclass"> 
               <img id="zoomremove" src="imag/bdelete.png"height="15"/>          
         </div>
         <div  class="loaddialog" style="border:1px solid black; text-align:center;">
              <img style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" id="zoomimg" src="" />
          </div>
      </div>
```

I've opened this in a dialog, the image in the loaddialog class is coming out of the div if the image is large. here is the dialog initialization.

```
   var height1 = screen.height-100;
   $('#zoomdialog').dialog({
    maxHeight: height1,
autoOpen: false,
width: '40%',
modal:true,
resizable: false,
draggable: false
});
```

How to fix the image in the div? Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use css property overflow:hidden for the container div. It will only show the part of image which fits the div height. (I am assuming it does not matter to you)

Comment: Is the image still coming out of the div?

Comment: did you apply overflow:hidden to the div with class "loaddialog"?